# Assessing a nested dict in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which mostly looks like this as

```py
result = {
   {
   "Dogs":{
      "original":[
         72,
         15.34386
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         4
      ]
   },
   "Cats":{
      "original":[
         24.716667,
         21.563121
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         2,
         4
      ]
   },
   "Lions":{
      "original":[
         15.761111,
         15.761111,
         15.761111
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4
      ]
   },
   "Bulls":{
      "original":[
         7.961111,
         7.055556,
         44.45,
         35.644444,
         35.644444,
         17.805556,
         17.805556,
         70.988889,
         35.527778
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4
      ]
   },
   "ivupstream-lix-frontend-0/invisualize LATENCY campaign-manager-web to RESTLI lixFrontendTreatmentsV2 on lix-frontend":{
      "original":[
         37.386364,
         28.289394
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4
      ]
   },
   "isnake":{
      "original":[
         18.399561,
         18.399561,
         20.361258,
         20.361258,
         18.674232,
         18.674232,
         18.248904
      ],
      "result":[
         1,
         2,
         3,
         4
      ]
   }
}
```

I have tried to extract the data out of it, but I don't know the best pythonic way to do so.

```
>>> for i in result.items():
...     print(i['Dogs'])
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

This somehow returns in this ^ and i am not sure how to deal with nested dictionary in general, though I tried a couple of ways.

I want to iterate over the dictionary and get `result` & `original` for each set of dict keys. What is the most pythonic way to do so ???

Comment: you can use `values()` method `for i in result.values(): print(i['Dogs'])`

Answer (score 0):

`.items` returns two args in each iteration, key and value.

```
for k, v in result.items():
    print(k, v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Zaven's answer, a bit more verbose and closer to requirements of the question:

```py
for k,v in result.items():
   r = v["result"]
   o = v["original"]
   print(k,r,o)
```